# Looking for a replacement to a static helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static, static-libraries, static-methods

I have an MVC ASP.NET project and I currently use a static ViewModelHelper class which has several methods (1 for each view model) that take in certain parameters and model objects and generate the view model objects for me to return to my views from my controllers. They are currently all static and the class as a whole is stateless, I just use it when I want to instantiate an instance of the view models because some of the data requires rather complex logic.

Would these methods be better off as constructors in the View Model classes? My understanding was it is better not to have any logic in the View Models, but I could be wrong. Or is there perhaps a design pattern I should be using here to help me create these View Models?

Comment: ViewModels can definitely contain logic. You might be confused about the term POCO and the fact that POCO's generally have no logic - but ViewModels most certainly do. Its not a good idea to have logic in _Views_ ... but definitely in the Models that serve the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of your project's architecture and design how your ViewModels should look like and where/how they should be initialized. It seems that right now your ViewModels are DTOs and you initialize them with a factory approach. That is fine, but I'd suggest to actually embrace the abstract factory pattern then and make sure that the factory implementation doesn't get overloaded with unrelated responsibilities. That is an inherit problem of "utility" classes that should make every developer wary.

On the other hand, view-related initialization logic, e.g. populating select lists, can very well be located in the ViewModels themselves. In that case you should be wary of duplication.

Another possible approach would be to utilize a builder pattern.

Either way can be a clean solution if you use it exclusively and not mix and match. And as long as you keep it clean, of course. ;)

Without having seen that rather complex logic, I'd suggest you check why the initialization logic is that complex to begin with, though. And if it really has to be. Maybe some business logic snuck in there?

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModels should be just DTOs, classes with properties only. No logic. Put logic in other classes (services or full business logic, depends) and have them populate the ViewModel.

I'm aware to the fact that this answer seems very short relative to the substantial design consideration, but that's the core of it. For reasoning etc. please have a look at some full-fledge ASP.NET MVC solutions that demonstrate it, like https://prodinner.codeplex.com/.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with "No logic" as a flat out rule. Certainly not hard and fast business logic - but definitely some logic should find its way into a ViewModel. For example, we have ViewModels that decide what CSS class a DOM element should have based on the conditions met by the ViewModel. They aren't a business concern, they are a concern of the view.. but the logic has no place inside the View.

Comment: ViewModels do have logic related to the UI, such as when i click a button, what colour to display something, or how to present the DTO to the UI ie. formatted double values. Logic a ViewModel should not include is business logic such as how data in a DTO is calculated.